# Google Docs SpreadSheet Script - How do I reference a specific Cell in a row as a condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following script (some of which I found and modified to my needs:

```
function onedit(e) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheetName = "Completed";
  var sourceSheetName = "Eligibility & Pre-Auths"
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  var sourceSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sourceRow = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var targetRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  if (sourceSheet.getName() == SourceSheetName) {;
    if (sourceRow[22]=="Yes") {;
      if (targetRow > targetSheet.getMaxRows()) targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetRow - 1);
      sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRow, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo    (targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, 1));
      sourceSheet.deleteRow(sourceRow);
    };
  };
}
```

Everything seems to working except my condition  - if (sourceRow[22]=="Yes")

I am new to this, so I know I am just not referencing it correctly.

I am just trying to check if the text "Yes" is in column 22 of the current row.  I am executing this script on edit.  So basically, when a "Yes" is entered in this fieild, I am moving this record to the sheet called "Completed"

Answer (score 1):

the statement `getRow()` returns an integer, the number of the row of that range, what you want is the value of the 22cd cell in that row , so try

```
  var sourceRow = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var sourceRowValue = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRow,1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxColumn()).getValues();
```

and then to get the cell value condition :

```
    if (sourceRowValue[0][21]=="Yes") {;
     ...
```

The result of `getValues()` is always a 2 dimension array, that's the reason for the `[0]` and is 0 indexed >> changed to 21

Note that I guess your code could be simpler if you use `sourceSheet.getActiveCell().getValue()` which returns directly the value of the cell you are writing to...

try this small example where I get the Value **and** the column index:

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cellValue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue()
ss.getRange('A1').setValue(cellValue+' in col '+ss.getActiveCell().getColumn())
}
```